# Calling fortran executable file from matlab is much slower

Tags: matlab, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I have a fortran code compiled into a exe file. I can run it directly through the command line, or simply call the executable from matlab. This two approaches lead to massively different execution speeds and I am unsure why.

If I run the executable file from the command line, the first part of the code runs in **1,000** seconds with all cores/threads of my computer being used:

[image]

If instead I call the fortran executable from matlab it does not use all cores/threads and takes approximately **1,400** seconds to run.

[image]

I am calling the code using: `system('path\LoopFortranToMatlab.exe')`

Comment: I have edit the question to add some more clarity.

Comment: Does the Fortran program interact with MATLAB in any way? Does it use any of MATLAB's libraries? The `.exe` extension makes this look like Windows, is that the OS you're using? Is the executable 64-bit or 32-bit? Are you doing anything else in MATLAB at the same time? A [mre] would be quite helpful. Note that `system` should start a new process (at least it does so on POSIX systems) so the CPU usage would be separate from that of MATLAB.

Comment: No interaction between matlab and fortran. It is literally a standalone executable fortran file that I just want to run in fortran. Not doing anything at the same time in matlab. system does seem to start a new process under the matlab (I updated the picture above). I will try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Perhaps MATLAB is setting core affinity of the child process in some way. From [Matlab sometimes won't thread mldivide on Intel Core i9-10980XE](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/587768-matlab-sometimes-won-t-thread-mldivide-on-intel-core-i9-10980xe) maybe setting the ``KMP_AFFINITY`` environment variable will have an effect. Under which version of MATLAB and Windows do you see the issue in? Also what is the processor in your PC?

Comment: Matlab R2022b, Windows 10 Enterprise and Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.49 GHz  (2 processors)

Comment: Try forcing the number of threads used by your Fortran program by inserting `call omp_set_num_threads(<number_of_physical_cores>)` at the beginning.

Comment: I have done that. Both set to number of physical cores and also to the number of thread. Neither change made a difference.